Blazor Navigation on a Condition
In a Blazor server application I have the following code in markup part:
@if (_patientId == 0 || AppState == null || AppState.SelectedPatient == null || AppState.SelectedPatient.PatientId == 0)
{
    nm.NavigateTo("/patientlist");
}
else
{
//do something else
}

and in OninitilizeAsync, I have:
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    if (_patientId == 0 || AppState == null || AppState.SelectedPatient == null || AppState.SelectedPatient.PatientId == 0)
    {
        nm.NavigateTo("/patientlist");
    }


}

Do I need to have this check both in the markup part and the OnInitializedAsync? The intent is that if the component receives an invalid patient id, the user should be redirected to another page. Is it safe to remove the navigation from the markup part and just let OnInit handle it? Will I run into any exceptions?
_patientId is a parameter that is part of the page url. AppState is a service used to maintain state of the application.

The most appropriate place depends on how do you get _patientId and AppState. An async process in  OnInitializedAsync?

So _patientId is a parameter that is part of the page url. AppState is a service used to maintain state of the application.
